# Evaluating $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}n\int_{0}^{1}\left(\cos x-\sin x\right)^n\text{ d}x$

Tags: integration

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}n\int_{0}^{1}\left(\cos x-\sin x\right)^n\text{ d}x$$

A) $ \infty$

B) $ 0$

C) $ 1$

D) $ \frac{1}{2}$

E) $\cos 1$

Source: admission 2015 Technical University of Cluj-Napoca

I tried with this result, but I'm not if it holds

If $f:[a,b]\rightarrow R$ f is differentiable with derivative nonzero, and $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty}\int_a^b f^n(x)dx=0$  then $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} n \cdot \int_a^b f^n(x)dx=\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{f^n(b)}{f'(b)}-\frac{f^n(a)}{f'(a)}\right)$

I used $f(x) = cosx - sinx $ but I'm not sure if $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty}\int_a^b f^n(x)dx=0$

I have tried with this too, $\cos x-\sin x= \frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}\cos (x+\frac{\pi}{4})$, but at one moment I can't continue... 
I can find a recurrence formula, but it's very complicated and I can't see the limit...

Comment: Any tries, thoughts or comments yourself on the problem?

Comment: I have tried  with this, but I'm not sure if it's correct <br> $f:[a,b]\rightarrow R$ if $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty}\int_a^b f^n(x)dx=0 $ then $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} n \cdot \int_a^b f^n(x)dx=\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{f^n(b)}{f'(b)}-\frac{f^n(a)}{f'(a)}\right)$

Comment: I think $\cos x-\sin x= \frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}\cos (x+\frac{\pi}{4})$ will be useful.

Comment: Thank you, I have tried with this too, $\cos x-\sin x= \frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}\cos (x+\frac{\pi}{4})$, but at one moment I can't continue...
I can find a recurrence formula, but it's very complicated and I can't see the limit...

Comment: Maybe it gets easier (more transparent) if you write this as $\cos x-\sin x=\sqrt{2}\sin(\pi/4-x)$ and then use the formula you have (which I was not aware of, I'm curious to see the source of it). Then, one of the parts in the limit will be 0 and the other one 1, so the final answer seems to be C).

Comment: Thank you for your answers!
I will try later with $\cos x-\sin x=\sqrt{2}\sin(\pi/4-x)$ and I will come back tomorrow...

Comment: to mickep: the source of the formula is http://pro-didactica.ro/forum/index.php?forumID=8&ID=20763&start=0

Comment: For $n>0$ split the integral into $\int _0^{g(n)}$ $+\int_{g(n}^1$ with $g(n)= (\log n)/\sqrt n.$  For sufficiently large $n$ we have $x\in [g(n),1]\to |\cos x-sin x|$ $<|\cos g(n)-\sin g(n)|$ and  $x\in [0,g(n)]\to$  $1-x\leq \cos x-\sin x\leq (1-x)(1+(g(x)^2).$

Comment: My last line should say $x\in [0,g(n)\to 1-x\leq \cos x-\sin x\leq (1-x)(1+x^2)\leq (1-x)(1+g(n)^2).$ And in the  middle line, "<" should be "$\leq$".

Comment: @user254665 How are you obtaining these bounds?  For large $n$, and $x\in[0,g(n)]$, $\cos x-\sin x=1-x-\frac12x^2+O(x^3)$.  This is certainly not greater than $1-x$ for large enough $n$.

Comment: i likely made an elementary algebra error. But I was only intending to  give a hint as to the method,           I may re-write it , but not today.Pussycat has broken foot (seriously)

Comment: @user254665 Sorry to hear about your kitty.  Hope he/she recovers soon.

Comment: $$n\int_{0}^{1}\left(\cos x-\sin x\right)^n\,dx\sim n\int_0^\epsilon (1-x)^n\,dx\sim n\int_0^\epsilon e^{-nx}\,dx\sim 1$$

Comment: Very minor edit required for post: cos, sin with \cos, \sin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\cos x-\sin x$.  We note that for $x\in[0,1]$, the maximum of $f(x)$ occurs at $x=0$ for which $f(0)=1$.

And for any number $0<a < \pi/4$, $x\in [a,\pi/4]$, $0<f(x)<\cos( a) -\sin (a)<1$.

Now, we choose a positive number $\delta<\pi/2-1$.  Then, we write the integral of interest as the sum

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1 (\cos x-\sin x)^n\,dx&=\int_{0}^{\delta} (\cos x-\sin x)^n\,dx+\int_{\delta}^{\pi/2-1} (\cos x-\sin x)^n\,dx\\\\
&+\int_{\pi/2-1}^{\pi/4}(\cos x-\sin x)^n\,dx+\int_{\pi/4}^{1}(\cos x-\sin x)^n\,dx\\\\
&=\int_{0}^{\delta} (\cos x-\sin x)^n\,dx+\int_{\delta}^{\pi/2-1} (\cos x-\sin x)^n\,dx \tag 1\\\\
&+(1+(-1)^n)\int_{\pi/2-1}^{\pi/4}(\cos x-\sin x)^n\,dx 
\end{align}$$

---

Now, we can see that the second and third integrals on the right-hand side of $(1)$ are positive and bounded by $(1-\pi/4)(\cos \delta-\sin \delta)^n$ and $2(1-\pi/4)(\sin (1)-\cos (1))^n$, respectively.  Therefore,

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}n\int_{\delta}^1(\cos x-\sin x)^n\,dx=0$$

---

For the first integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$, we proceed as follows.  Given any $\epsilon>0$, we now choose $0<\delta<\epsilon$.  Then, using the mean-value theorem, we find that for $x\in[0,\delta]$, the function $f$ satisfies the inequalities

$$1-(1+\epsilon)x \le f(x)\le 1-x \tag 2$$

Applying $(2)$ to the first integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$ yields

$$n\int_{0}^{\delta}\left(1-(1+\epsilon)x\right)^n\,dx\le n\int_{0}^{\delta} (\cos x-\sin x)^n\,dx\le n\int_{0}^{\delta} (1- x)^n\,dx \tag 3$$

Evaluating the integrals in $(3)$ that bound $ n\int_{0}^{\delta} (\cos x-\sin x)^n\,dx$ reveals

$$\frac{n}{n+1}\frac{\left(1-(1-(1+\epsilon)\delta)^{n+1}\right)}{1+\epsilon}\le n\int_{0}^{\delta} (\cos x-\sin x)^n\,dx\le \frac{n}{n+1}\left(1-(1-\delta)^{n+1}\right) \tag 3$$

Using the squeeze theorem ($n\to \infty$) we see that for any given $\epsilon>0$, we can choose $0<\delta <\epsilon$ so that

$$1-\epsilon\le \frac{1}{1+\epsilon}\le \lim_{n\to \infty}n\int_{0}^{\delta} (\cos x-\sin x)^n\,dx\le 1$$

Therefore, we have

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\lim_{n\to \infty}n\int_{0}^{\delta} (\cos x-\sin x)^n\,dx=1}$$

Comment: Thank you!
I think your solution is correct and I understand everything, excepting inequalities (2), they look correct but I'm not sure how exactly to prove...

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.

Comment: As for inequality $(2)$, start with the MVT.  Then use, $\sin \delta +\cos \delta<1+\delta$.

Comment: @DrMV I voted your solution 14 hours ago, but unfortunately I'm new, my reputation is just 9 and the vote is not visible until I don't have reputation 15,  also I think I'm not a math beginner but I'm impressed by your solution  Thank you again!